# How to delete the specific files and folders that begin and cotains with some numbers and titles?

Tags: php, string

I came up with this questioin. My background is from the Node.js. I am not usually quite used to be in PHP. That's why I'm aksing this question to solve the current issues.

The issues is that's to says I have certain **Files and Folders** that contains with a specific letters and number at the beginning. As you can see given by down below with a scrrenshot.

[image]

I just learn and writing some php code that I grabbed it from the internet resources. Take a look at what's my code:

1. I want this to detele this all folders which contains letters "**exp_**" and all the files names start with this numbers "**xx-xx-xx**" etc.
2. I created **delete.php**. When I'd called this file via the browser, I want to **achieve to delete all the files and folder** which for the **No. 1** case.
3. **All these folders and files are generated in everdays. That's why I do want to clean all those data.**

```
<?php
$path = "test";

if(!unlink($path)){
 echo "File has not deleted yet.";
} else {
 echo "Successfully deleted!";
}

?>
```

**Is there any how any solution to solve this issues?** I will appreciate all in advanced who are giving me idea and suggestions from you guys.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
$files = new DirectoryIterator(__DIR__);
foreach ($files as $file) {  
    if ( ($file->isDir() and strpos($file->getFilename(),'exp_')!==false) || ($file->isFile() and $file->getFilename() == date('d-m-Y') )  ) {
        unlink($file->getPathname());
    } 
}
```

---

Thus, all folders with names like `exp_` and files with today's date will be deleted.

Comment: Instead of making static value just like `$removes = ['exp_','23-04-22','24-04-22'];`I want to get dynamic value. Because I forgot to says, all my files and folders are added in every days.

Comment: @ChenLay I have changed my answer, see if this closes your issue

Comment: Oops! When I'd called delete.php alongside with your code implementation, it's deleted the rest of all my existing data. What I have to do? :(

Comment: @ChenLay sorry, corrected the condition, repeat :(/

Comment: The latest edited codes didn't work.